# How to get value from first page to second page in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I want to pass values from one page to another page in ionic 2.

Example:
First Page:
*First Name*: abc
*Last Name*: xyz

Second Page:
*First Name*: get the value of First name
*Last Name*: get the value of Last name

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got two solutions to solve it.

1. If you want to pass the values as parameters from FirstPage to SecondPage then you could use NavParams.

In the first page:

```
this.navController.push(SecondPage, { yourParameterName: yourParameterValue });
```

In the second page:

```
onPageDidEnter() {
    this.yourClassVariable = this.navParams.get('yourParameterName');
}
```

note that if you want to pass something from SecondPage to FirstPage too, you could pass a callback as parameter and call that one in the SecondPage to assign a value in FirstPage before doing the back action (this.navController.pop())

2.You could also solve the sharing of values thru the help of an injectable service

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
   private string $value;

   setValue(newValue:string) {
       this.$value = newValue;
   }

   getValue():string {
      return this.$value;
   }
 }
```

And then in both of your pages, you could add the service as providers and set/get the value you are interesting in

```
@Component({
   providers: [MyService]
})
export class FirstPage {
    constructor(private myService:MyService) {
    }

    private anyWhere() {
       this.myService.setValue('myValue');
       this.myService.getValue();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Small correction: `MyService` should not be added as a provider of both pages, because then a new instance of it will be created and there won't be any persistence of the data. Instead, it should only be a provider of a mutual parent of the pages, or if one page is the parent component of the second - it should be a provider of the first one.

Comment: thx for the add-on, agree. Personally I list all my providers once in the main class app.ts